# How do I send key presses and mouse movements to an application running in the background? (In Python)

Tags: python, automation

Ok, so what I want to do is allow my program to send mouse movements and keypresses (both mouse and keyboard) to a particular task without having to be tabbed into the task so I can do other things on my computer with the mouse and keyboard while the task runs. Is it possible to do this relatively simply with existing python modules?

example of what I want to do:

> task='application name'
>
> task.leftclick
>
> task.moveX(int)
>
> task.moveY(int)
>
> task.keypress(r)

All while being able to use my mouse and keyboard normally on a different application.
Thanks for the help in advance!
(Python3.6)

Comment: I think you cannot use the mouse in the foreground and at the same time use it in the backgroun, as there is only one input. But , try https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/. Autoit has certain features like controlcommand and controlclick that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who happens upon this post, I found https://pypi.org/project/ahk/ I haven't looked into it fully but either you can use this or create an auto hotkey script and just call that with you python code to achieve what I wanted to do in the question.